# Sending data from React to Node backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, post

I am building a React and Node app and I am trying to send data from React to Node and print it in console. Here is my code:

React code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Test extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { name: 'Serban' };
  this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}

tick() {
   console.log(this.state.name);
   const article = { n: this.state.name };
axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api', article)
}

componentDidMount() {
// Simple POST request with a JSON body using axios

   
}

render() {
   return(
<div>
<button onClick={this.tick}>Send</button>
</div>
   );
}

}

export default Test;
```

Node code:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require("cors");



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(cors())


app.post('/api', function(req, res) {

var nume = req.body.n;
console.log("Salut " + nume);

});
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
Server listening on 3001
TypeError: Cannot read property 'n' of undefined
at C:\react-efactura\server\index.js:16:23
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\react- 
efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\react-efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\react-efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\react- 
efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\react-efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\react- 
efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\react-efactura\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at cors (C:\react-efactura\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:188:7)
at C:\react-efactura\node_modules\cors\lib\index.js:224:17
```

What am I doing wrong ? I have tried diferent stuff that I googled but none work. It seems that it manages to do the request from React but it doesn`t send the value. Why doesn`t it send the value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, Node doesn't automatically make `req.body` available. You have to manually add a middleware to parse incoming data from the browser, and construct `req.body` which can then be used. For years, the `body-parser` module was used, now Express 4.16+ can do that directly with `app.use(express.json());`

Some interesting read about that : https://medium.com/@mmajdanski/express-body-parser-and-why-may-not-need-it-335803cd048c